# MVC 3 knockout else if string != ""

Tags: asp.net-mvc, if-statement, knockout.js

```
<!-- ko if: ItemType() > 0 -->
  <div ...   </div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko else if: OfferId() != "" -->
  <div ...      </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

ItemType and OfferId is properties in the object and added  by

```
public string OfferId { get; set; }
public int ItemType { get; set; }

p.ItemType = ko.observable(item.ItemType);
p.OfferId = ko.observable(item.OfferId);
```

the first if statement works but not the else if even when to ItemType is 0 and OfferId is something. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not typing javascript before the colon. this is the name of a binding in knockout. there is no `else if` binding in knockout.

you will need to do:

```
<!-- ko if: ItemType() > 0 -->
    <div ...   </div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: ItemType() <= 0 && OfferId() != "" -->
  <div ...      </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

for a full list of bindings, see the left column at http://knockoutjs.com

The "Control Flow" section has the `if` binding - no `else if`.

Answer (score 0):

remove the else in the second statement. as far as i know there is no else if binding in knockout.

```
<!-- ko if: OfferId() != "" && ItemType() == 0 -->
  <div ...      </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```